# Cypress Testing Angular Application on BitBucket Pipeline

Tags: angular, cypress, bitbucket-pipelines

Thanks in advance. So I am looking at implementing a BitBucket Pipeline for our Angular project, but seem to fail when running on the server itself. The application is building successful but when running tests, they all fail.

The tests all fail at the initial step, all for the same reason. Just to let you know that I am fairly new to Cypress, but assume the issue is with the pipeline configuration.

Error

```
1) Registration Incorrect email:
 CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find element: '.headerMenu__item-register', but never found it.
  at Object.cypressErr (http://localhost:4200/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:86206:11)
```

Package.json Scripts

```
"start-silent": "ng serve",
"cy:run": "cypress run --browser chrome --headless",
"start-server-test": "start-server-and-test start-silent http://localhost:4200 cy:run",
```

Pipeline Configuration

```
image: cypress/browsers:chrome67-ff57
options:
  max-time: 30

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Install & Build
        caches:
          - npm
          - cypress
          - node
        script:
          - npm ci
          - npm run build:prod
    - step:
        name: E2E tests
        caches:
          - node
          - cypress
        script:
          - npm ci
          - npm run cy:verify
          - npm run start-server-test
        artifacts:
          - cypress/screenshots/**
          - cypress/videos/**
definitions:
  caches:
    npm: $HOME/.npm
    cypress: $HOME/.cache/Cypress
```

Comment: do the test run fine locally? and can you maybe post the test-code where the error occurs?